# Invoking animation in a different xaml control on button click WITHOUT resorting to ViewModels

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Header}" Background="Blue" Name="PanelHeader">
                        <Button.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Stackpanel"
                                      Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                                      From="0" To="100" Duration="0:0:3" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Button.Triggers>
                    </Button>
```

I want to move the storyboard animation to the stack panel declaration and simply invoke that animation from the button click.

Most examples I've found resort to using the viewmodel or other codebehind interjections.

Answer (score 0):

this example doesn't use code behind nor ViewModel

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0290__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/StartandstopanAnimationwithButtonactions.htm